# How can i manipulate array with json encoded data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the array of data like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lot_no] => ["A001","A001","B002"]
            [qty] => ["4","5","6"]
            [weight] => ["4","5","6"]
            [particular] => ["100% cashmere","100% cashmere","20% silk 80% cashmere"]
            [remarks] => ["4","5","6"]
        )

)
```

i want to throw this data in table shown in pic table no 1 like of the second pic. How can i do that?
[image: table no 1]
[image: Table 2]

Comment: Unclear question.. Explain your question in details

Comment: I want to throw the values of lot_no in the table as shown above pic 1
but i have table shown in above pic 2

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the loop of array in view

```
    <?php if (count($detailListDatas ) > 0): ?>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sno</th>
          <th>Particular</th>
          <th>Lot no</th>
          <th>Total Qty</th>
          <th>Total Weight</th>
          <th>Remark</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php $i=0;
          foreach ($detailListDatas as $row) ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i++?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['particular']; ?></td>
          ... similarly all the element
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No, it didn't help me out

Comment: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: what is your array name?

Comment: detailListDatas

Answer (score 0):

I tried your answer which didn't gave me the output i needed. Eventually i did it by myself like this

```
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>S.No</th>
                          <th>Particulars</th>
                          <th>Lot no</th>
                          <th>Total Qty</th>
                          <th>Total Weight</th>
                          <th>Remarks</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <?php $sn =1;
                                foreach ($detailListDatas as $key ) {
                                     $json_array['lot_no']  = json_decode($key['lot_no'], true);
                                     $lot_no = $json_array['lot_no'];
                                     $i = count($lot_no);
                                     $json_array['qty'] = json_decode($key['qty'],true);
                                     $qty = $json_array['qty'];
                                     $json_array['weight'] = json_decode($key['weight'],true);
                                     $weight = $json_array['weight'];
                                     $json_array['particular'] = json_decode($key['particular'],true);
                                     $particular = $json_array['particular'];
                                     $json_array['remarks'] = json_decode($key['remarks'],true);
                                     $remarks = $json_array['remarks'];
                                     for ($j=0; $j < $i ; $j++) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td><?php echo $sn?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $particular[$j];?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $lot_no[$j];?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $qty[$j];?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $weight[$j];?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $remarks[$j];?></td>
                                        </tr>
                              <?php   $sn++; } ?>
                                <?php  } ?>
                    </tbody>
               </table>
```

Comment: Please minimally tab your code to reduce unnecessary scrolling and provide some explanation with your code so that future SO readers can benefit.  (Your answer is in the low-quality moderation queue.)